# UNTextInputNotificationAction not called when app is killed or screen is locked swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, remote-notifications

**This is how I register the notification actions**

```
func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

        guard granted else { return }

        let action = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: replyActionIdentifier, title: "Answer message", options: [UNNotificationActionOptions.init(rawValue: 0)], textInputButtonTitle: "Send", textInputPlaceholder: "Type your message")

        let newsCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryIdentifier,
                                                  actions: [action],
                                                  intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                  options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([newsCategory])

        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}
```

**Here I conform the protocol UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and handle the notification action**

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    // check if there is information in push's payload
    guard let custom = userInfo["data"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        completionHandler()
        return
    }

    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case replyActionIdentifier:

        if let message = response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
            if message.userText.isEmpty { return }

            // encrypt the message
            let publicKey = try! PublicKey(pemEncoded: Constantes.PUSH_KEY)
            let clear = try! ClearMessage(string: message.userText, using: .utf8)
            let encrypted = try! clear.encrypted(with: publicKey, padding: .PKCS1)
            let messageUser = encrypted.base64String

            // data inside the push
            guard let user_id = custom["me"] as? String, let room_id = custom["room_id"] as? String else {
                completionHandler()
                return
            }

            // secutiry elements
            guard let token = String(data: Keychain.load("push_token")!, encoding: .utf8),
                let uuid = String(data: Keychain.load("UUID")!, encoding: .utf8) else {
                completionHandler()
                return
            }

            let key = Constantes.KEY
            let chats = Chats()

            // this executes an http request
            chats.sendMessage(token: token, uuid: uuid, key: key!, message: messageUser, user_id: user_id, room_id: room_id)
        }

    default: break
    }
    completionHandler()

}
```

}

In previous function I execute an http request to answer the message in the push notification. The real issue happens when I respond the message in the notification and hit Send button, and sometimes the http request is executed and sometimes it`s not. I already added background modes in the capabilities of my app, in fact I am receiving successfully notifications from api, the api is sending the value 'content-available' in 1. Finally, certificates .pem are working correctly in the server, so. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this problem and didn't having a clue why my quick reply was working if the app is in background but not when it's killed. Then I started looking for something through the source code and stumbled upon this in the `UNNotificationCenter`:

```
// The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction. The delegate must be set before the application returns from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler
```

If you read good the last part of the comment it's saying that the delegate must be set before returning from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

This is where my mistake was. I was setting the delegate in the completion of `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings`

So all you have to do is make sure that you set the delegate like this `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` returned